# What's the meaning of "Current language: auto; currently objective-c"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdb

When I used Xcode to debug my iOS program, gdb displayed it on console view, and no error did occur.

I just want to know the specific meaning of the output "Current language:  auto; currently objective-c".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that gdb is set to automatically infer the correct (programming) language from the source code associated with whatever frame you happen to be looking at.

From [the GDB Manual](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html):

> 15.1.3 Having gdb Infer the Source Language
>
> To have gdb set the working language automatically, use `set language
>   local' or`set language auto'. gdb then infers the working language.
>   That is, when your program stops in a frame (usually by encountering a
>   breakpoint), gdb sets the working language to the language recorded
>   for the function in that frame. If the language for a frame is unknown
>   (that is, if the function or block corresponding to the frame was
>   defined in a source file that does not have a recognized extension),
>   the current working language is not changed, and gdb issues a warning.
>
> This may not seem necessary for most programs, which are written
>   entirely in one source language. However, program modules and
>   libraries written in one source language can be used by a main program
>   written in a different source language. Using `set language auto' in
>   this case frees you from having to set the working language manually.